# construction of a special sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

We would like to find a sequence $ (f_n)_n $ of differentiable functions such that $$ \int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 \left| f'_n(t)\right|^p t^{p-1} dt \to 0,\ n \to + \infty $$ and  $ f_n(1) = 0,\ f_n(1- \frac{1}{n}) = 1, $ where $ p \geq 2 $ is a real number. I tried with the affin sequence $ f_n(t) = -n(t-1) $ but it does not fulfill all the conditions. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\geq 2$ we have $t\geq 1-1/n\geq 1/2$, so
$$\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 \left| f'_n(t)\right|^p dt\leq 2^{p-1}\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 \left| f'_n(t)\right|^p t^{p-1} dt \to 0.$$
Moreover, from Holder inequality we get ($1/p+1/q=1$)
$$
\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 \left| f'_n(t)\right| dt \leq 
\left(\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 \left| f'_n(t)\right|^p dt\right)^{1/p}
\cdot
\left(\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 1^q dt\right)^{1/q}
=
\left(\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 \left| f'_n(t)\right|^p dt\right)^{1/p}\cdot \frac 1{n^{1/q}}\to 0.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1 \left| f'_n(t)\right| dt \geq 
\left|\int_{1- \frac{1}{n}}^1  f'_n(t)  dt \right| = |f_n(1)-f_n(1-1/n)| = |0-1|=1.
$$

This shows that it seems there are no such functions.

Comment: As long as $f_n$ is absolutely continuous or similar, so the fundamental theorem applies.